# context != null': is not true in scaffold.dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, assert, scaffold

I have seen similar errors on here but not sure if the same applies to mine

I am dealing with an assent context error in scaffold.dart folder

attached is the image with errors and code

if there are any guides to solve this will be appreciated

[image]

Image of Splash screen
clicking on the Splash screen error takes me to line 50

[image]

Comment: try `context != undefined`

Comment: @ElnatalDebebe It threw an error

Comment: Please post your own code (`SplashScreenController`).  The fact that the Flutter SDK has a non-null assertion here is unlikely to be a bug.

Comment: @Nitrodon

I have added the codes for the splash Screen

Comment: There is no context in fact !!

Comment: ``context`` is ``null``